# Errors on Deno JSX examples: Property 'reason' does not exist on type 'AbortSignal'

Tags: jsx, deno

I ran the example JSX Deno script as [shown here](https://deno.com/deploy/docs/using-jsx)

```
deno run --allow-net=:8000 https://deno.com/examples/hello.jsx
```

and got the following output

```
Check https://deno.com/examples/hello.jsx
error: TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'reason' does not exist on type 'AbortSignal'.
    return Promise.reject(createAbortError(signal.reason));
                                                  ~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std@0.140.0/async/abortable.ts:27:51

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'reason' does not exist on type 'AbortSignal'.
  const abort = () => waiter.reject(createAbortError(signal.reason));
                                                            ~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std@0.140.0/async/abortable.ts:30:61

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'reason' does not exist on type 'AbortSignal'.
    throw createAbortError(signal.reason);
                                  ~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std@0.140.0/async/abortable.ts:46:35

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'reason' does not exist on type 'AbortSignal'.
  const abort = () => waiter.reject(createAbortError(signal.reason));
                                                            ~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std@0.140.0/async/abortable.ts:49:61

Found 4 errors.
```

Is there something I'm missing here? For the record, the `hello.js` example works great when I run that.

Comment: I can reproduce the errors on Deno versions < 1.22.0 but not on later versions, so probably you just need to upgrade your version

Comment: Thank you, not sure why I didn't think of that!